# Удаление из таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос

> `SELECT * FROM images,albums WHERE
> images.gallery_id=albums.uid`

Как из таблицы **images** удалить записи которые равны записям в таблице **albums**, в данном случае `images.gallery_id=albums.uid`?

Answer (score 4):

```
DELETE FROM images
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM albums
    WHERE albums.uid = images.gallery_id
)
```

Вроде должен нормально работать и такой вариант (я в нем не уверен, поэтому наобум не надо его прогонять)

```
DELETE FROM images
INNER JOIN albums ON images.gallery_id = albums.uid
```

Comment: пишет syntaxss error во втором случае, а первый удаляет все подряд из таблицы images

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, только что проверил, вариант с exists удаляет все те записи, для которых существуте связанная запись в albums

Comment: @LLIAKAJI для всех есть связанные альбомы? Какие точные критерии записи, которую нужно удалить?

Comment: я уже разобрался, условие не правильно вставлял